# processing $_POST in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

How do i do this in codeigniter?

```
$cuisineArr = isset($_POST['cuisine']) ? $_POST['cuisine'] : array();
```

I read somewhere that using $_Post[''] direct is a not the right way and post() should be used
instead. But how do i do the same in codeigniter?

I'm getting an array from a group of checkbox, then converting it to csv. The non-codeigniter code is below:

```
$cuisineArr = isset($_POST['cuisine']) ? $_POST['cuisine'] : array();
$cuisineArrCSV = implode(',',$cuisineArr);
echo $cuisineArrCSV;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the CodeIgniter [`Input`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html) class.

Here's what your code should look like:

```
$cuisine = $this->input->post('cuisine');
$cuisineArr = ($cuisine != FALSE) ? $cuisine : array();
$cuisineArrCSV = implode(',',$cuisineArr);
echo $cuisineArrCSV;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$cuisineArr = ($this->input->post("cuisine") != false) ? $this->input->post("cuisine") : array();
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: It is also worth noting that the input class is automatically initialized so you do not have to load or autoload it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the class input and post CodeIgniter there

```
if ($this->input->post())
```